# Change body font-size automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-size

I would like to know if there's a way to change the body font-size according to the screen width.

For example: When the screen's width **increases** with **1px**, the body font-size would change from **100% to 100.1%**

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Comment: As @CBroe pointed out: http://jsbin.com/vimexu/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use window resize event. For example, following code could be one.

```
var prevWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('body').css('font-size',(100 + ($(window).width() - prevWidth) / 100) + '%');
    prevWidth = $(window).width();
});
```